# change value of input made with react from chrome extension

Tags: reactjs, google-chrome-extension

I work on Chrome extension, i need to update lot of inputs of an html page made with React from numbers readed from CSV. I cannot update the web site.

-
An example of input copied from the rendered website :

```
  <td><input class="input input_small fpInput" value="29,4"></td>
```

-
How it's made (not sure 100% about that, had to read the uglified js source)

```
{
    key: "render",
    value: function () {
        return s.a.createElement("input", {
            className: "input input_small fpInput",
            value: this.state.value,
            onChange: this.handleChange,
            onBlur: this.handleSubmit,
            onFocus: this.handleFocus
        })
    }
}
```

-
Each time you change the input value a function is called and a POST is made to save it.

**I want to trigger the `onBlur()` or `onChange()` from my extension after i changed the input value to trigger the POST**

I tried this :

```
var el = document. ... .querySelector('input'); // the selector is simplied of course
el.value = 321;
el.onChange();  // ERROR onChange is not a function
el.onchange();  // ERROR onchange is not a function
el.handleChange(); // ERROR handleChange is not a function
```

Any idea please ?

Comment: You can do it without dispatching an event via  document.execCommand with insertText parameter.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

To elaborate a bit more on @varoons answer, which is factually correct albeit a bit short on explanation.

You can do so by injecting (dispatching, in browser terms) the event into the dom:

```
// Needs setAttribute to work well with React and everything, just `.value` doesn't cut it
// Also changed it to a string, as all attributes are strings (even for <input type="number" />)
el.setAttribute("value", "321"); 

// As @wOxxOm pointed out, we need to pass `{ bubbles: true }` to the options,
// as React listens on the document element and not the individual input elements
el.dispatchEvent(new Event("change", { bubbles: true }));
el.dispatchEvent(new Event("blur", { bubbles: true }));
```

This will actually call all the listeners, even those made with React (as is the case in your de-uglyfied code ;)) or made with simple `element.onChange = () => {...}` listeners.

Example: https://codesandbox.io/s/kml7m2nn4r

Comment: @wOxxOM what did you mean please ? the answers did not work for me :(

Comment: @AlainIb Actually I forgot something important (apart from bubbles: true) I'll update the answer!

Comment: @wOxxOm You are right, it needs `{ bubbles: true }` ! Thanks :)

Answer (score 12):

You can't call a React component's method directly from the DOM element it has rendered. You need to trigger an event that bubbles up so that React can catch it at the [`document`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document) level and process it normally, as it would do with a real one.

#### ✨ Document.execCommand():

As pointed out by @woxxom in the comments, the easiest way to do that might be to focus the inputs and then use [`Document.execCommand()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/execCommand):

```js
const input1 = document.getElementById('input1');
const input2 = document.getElementById('input2');

input1.focus();
document.execCommand('insertText', false, 'input1');

input2.focus();
document.execCommand('insertText', false, 'input2');
```

```html
<input id="input1" />
<input id="input2" />
```

#### ⚒️ Manually Dispatching Events:

Otherwise, you might try manually [dispatching a `change`, `input` and/or `blur` event](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/Events/Creating_and_triggering_events) using the [Event() constructor](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/Event) in those fields after you change their value.

Also, note `Event()`'s second optional argument contains a field, `bubbles`, that is `false` by default. **You need that one to be `true`**. Otherwise, this won't work, as React is listening for events on the [`document`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document).

Additionally, you might need to use [`Element.setAttribute()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/setAttribute) too, as that will update the `value` attribute on the DOM (the initial value on the field), while `element.value` will update the current value (and so the display value). Usually, though, it's not needed. For more on this see [What is the difference between properties and attributes in HTML?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6003819/what-is-the-difference-between-properties-and-attributes-in-html).

This approach might have some timing issues you might need to handle using [`setTimeout`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/setTimeout) when updating multiple inputs, so if the first one works, I'd go for that one instead.

```js
const input1 = document.getElementById('input1');

// This updates the value displayed on the input, but not the DOM (you can do that with setAttribute,
// but it's not needed here):
input1.value = 'input1';

// Dispatch an "input" event. In some cases, "change" would also work:
input1.dispatchEvent(new Event('input', { bubbles: true }));

// It looks like only one field will be updated if both events are dispatched
// straight away, so you could use a setTimeout here:

setTimeout(() => {
  const input2 = document.getElementById('input2');
  input2.value = 'input2';
  input2.dispatchEvent(new Event('input', { bubbles: true }));    
});
```

```html
<input id="input1" />
<input id="input2" />
```

Comment: This worked for me!  I had the `blur` and `change` events, but I needed to add the `input` event as well.

Comment: Manually dispatching Events is working for me

Answer (score 2):

```
el.dispatchEvent(new CustomEvent("change"))
```

Comment: Just Event is fine, no need for Custom since you don't pass any data.